# JavaFX: multiple columns for same data type in TableView

Tags: javafx, tableview

I wonder if it's possible to make TableView so that it breaks data in multiple columns.
So, instead of having long list of checkbox-name pairs, it would break it in n columns:

```
[✓] Jim   [✓] Joe
[✓] Sue   [✓] Jane
[ ] Susan [✓] Mark
   .         .
   .         . 
   .         .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering your goal is layout-related, I would recommend you used a `TilePane` with checkbox-name pairs, rather than a `Table`. It would know automatically how to break the UI widgets into several columns.